# Cytoscape - isHeadless error, cytoscape cola layout

Tags: reactjs, cytoscape.js

I'm trying to add node when you click on another node. The canva can't even load, I've got always the same error : Cannot read properties of null (reading 'isHeadless'). I don't understand why.

There's the link of the sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-cytoscape-qxecel?file=/src/App.js
Thanks